# Deixar activity "escurecida" quando clico e abre um listview em cima da activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Tenho uma activity com itens (recyclerView), quando clico em um item, faço "aparecer" um listView por cima usando setVisible(VISIBLE). Quero que quando aparecer a listview, a activity em baixo fique mais escura. É exatamente o que acontece quando você vai agendar um lembrete de horário na google agenda.

Segue imagem abaixo do que quero fazer, olha como está escurecido a activity enquanto a list está por cima.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O exemplo que você deu utiliza um `AlertDialog`, acredito que é isso que você quer. Veja [na documentação oficial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html?hl=pt-br#AddingAList) se o exemplo de `AlertDialog` com listas te ajuda.

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu minha dúvida.